# Quickfix for C# problems in VS2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

is there something like a Quickfix in Eclipse IDE available in VisualStudio 2008?

Thanks,

Okami

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl-Period will do various things (adding using directives) etc but VS2008 itself doesn't do a lot. I'd recommend [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), which has rather more of this.